# TimerScheduleFixedRate()

Tags: java, timer

I am trying some **Timer Schedule** to implement it in my next program

and here is the code

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimerTask tasknew = new TimerScheduleAtFixedRate();// here is the erorr
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasknew,new Date(),1000);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("working at fixed rate");
    }
}
```

I don't know why the line on TimerScheduleFixedRate() gives the following error when the program runs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: TimerScheduleAtFixedRate.
  <init> at javaapplication1.TimerDemo.main(TimerDemo.java:11)
```

Comment: Please also share the error as well as the code for `TimerScheduleFixedRate`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: TimerScheduleAtFixedRate.<init>
 at javaapplication1.TimerDemo.main(TimerDemo.java:11)

Comment: this is the erorr when I run the code

Comment: it seems TimerScheduleAtFixedRate is not a valid java class because it cannot be compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the class wrongly... TimerScheduleFixedRateDelay is a class,

follow this example:

```
class SayHello extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
       System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
    }
 }

 // And From your main() method or any other method
 Timer timer = new Timer();
 timer.schedule(new SayHello(), 0, 5000);
```